# Why schema_of_json fails?

Tags: apache-spark

Why second transformation fails?

```
df
  .withColumn("schemaDetected", schema_of_json(lit("""{"Zipcode":704,"ZipCodeType":"STANDARD","City":"PARC PARQUE","State":"PR"}""")))
  .show(false)
//shows: struct<City:string,State:string,ZipCodeType:string,Zipcode:bigint>

df
  .withColumn("literal", lit("""{"Zipcode":704,"ZipCodeType":"STANDARD","City":"PARC PARQUE","State":"PR"}"""))
  .withColumn("schemaDetected", schema_of_json(col("literal")))
  .show(false)
// it fails:
// cannot resolve 'schema_of_json(`literal`)' due to data type mismatch: The input json should be a string literal and not null; however, got `literal`.;;
```

I need to get a columns schema but it only accepts a 'lit' included inside of the method, when I add a Column it fails. ¿why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The second transformation fails because when you pass a column containing a json string from a dataframe to `schema_of_json` function Spark can't be sure that each row json string of this column will evaluate to the same schema**

To understand why having the same schema for all rows is important, you must acknowledge that main use case for creation of `schema_of_json` function is to infer schema for [`from_json`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#from_json(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,schema:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function.

`from_json` transforms a json string to a `struct`, basically several new columns. And of course all rows in a dataframe should have the same columns. So, you have to ensure that when you use `from_json` on a dataframe, you pass the same schema to all rows.

At origin, you should have been able to pass a column that is not a `literal` to `schema_of_json`, as you can see in ticket [SPARK-24642](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24642). However, it meant to merge infered schema for each row. For instance, if you have the following dataframe:

```
+------------------+
| json_string      |
+------------------+
| {"a": 1}         |
| {"b": 2}         |
| {"a": 3, "c": 4} |
+------------------+
```

And you want to pass a schema returned by `schema_of_json` to `from_json` function, you have to infer schema `STRUCT<a INT, b INT, c INT>` to be able to have a consistent schema for all rows. To do so, you will need to transform `schema_of_json` to an aggregate function that will build schema by iterating over all values of argument column or to have schema inferences (like when you read an CSV). [It was considered not worth it](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24642?focusedCommentId=16525548&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16525548).

So, instead of being able to pass a dataframe column as argument, you can only pass `literal`, that you can get using function `lit` as it was implemented in [SPARK-24709](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24642)

`schema_of_json` was upgraded later in Spark 3.1 (see [SPARK-31044](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-31044)) to be able to take foldable columns, meaning columns that can be evaluated statically before query execution. An example of such foldable column is `regexp_replace(lit("""{"test":1}""", "1", "2"))`, that is not directly a `literal` but a transformation of a `literal`

**So to come back to your case, when you create a column from your `lit(...)`, Spark sees a column but not its content. As Spark doesn't see column's content, it can't be sure that values for this column are the same. But Spark has to ensure that schema generated by those values are the same so it has to be sure that input values are the same. So it throws an error basically saying "I can't be sure that for all rows, json strings contained in this column are the same"**

Comment: Thank you so much Vincent, my goal was identify which schema belongs to each json, I see this function does not fix for me, I will continue to think how to resolve this approach. Thanks