# Is there a way to guess the schema dynamically in Pyspark?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a table in Databricks, with a column as string dictionary as below -

```
+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |stringDictionary                                                                                              |
+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|abc|{"col1": "someValue", "col2" : "someValue", "col3" : "someValue"}                                             |
|def|{"col1" : "someValue", "col3": "someValue"}                                                                   |
|mnp|{"col1" : "someValue", "col2" : "someValue", "col3" : "someValue", "col4" : "someValue", "col5" : "someValue"}|
|abc|{"col4" : "someValue", "col5" : "someValue", "col6" : "someValue"}                                            |
+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now for each of the id's there can be multiple structures as shown.

I tried defining the Struct schema for few of them as below -

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,from_json

schema = StructType([ 
    StructField("col1",StringType(),True), 
    StructField("col2",StringType(),True), 
    StructField("col3",StringType(),True), 
    StructField("col4", StringType(), True)
  ])

dfJSON = sparkDF.withColumn("jsonData",from_json(col("stringDictionary"),schema)) \
                   .select("stringDictionary","jsonData.*","*")#.drop("stringDictionary")

display(dfJSON)
```

But this is not a good approach reason being every time a new element is added it won't suffice and will have to change the schema manually.

Is there a way to handle all such scenarios or guess the struct schema whenever this table or dataframe is read and flatten its corresponding `stringDictionary` to be a separate column of its own?

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I converted sparkDF's `stringDictionary` column to `MapType` using the below code -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df = (sparkDF.withColumn("cols", 
                          from_json( col("stringDictionary"), 
                                     MapType(StringType(), StringType())
                                    )
                         )
             .drop("stringDictionary")
       )
```

Now, column `cols` needs to be exploded as below -

```
df2 = df.select("id", explode("cols").alias("col_columns", "col_rows"))

display(df2)
```

Once, I have `col_columns` and `col_rows` as individual columns, all that is needed to do is `pivot` `col_columns` and aggregate it using its corresponding `first` `col_rows` as below -

```
df3 = df2.groupBy("id")
         .pivot("col_columns")
         .agg(first("col_rows"))

display(df3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [schema_of_json()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#schema_of_json) to dynamically make your schema, then use [MergeSchema](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#schema-merging) for schema evolution.

Be aware that in production environment, sometimes the json payload can be sent with wrong data type. Also, schema evolution doesn't work with nested structs.

Comment: schema_of_json will throw an error if I directly pass the stringDictionary `due to data type mismatch: The input json should be a foldable string expression and not null`

Comment: Wait, is this column really a string? Because shouldn't give this error

Comment: Yes it is indeed

Comment: You can't pass any string column to `schema_of_json` method, it has to be a foldable column (roughly meaning created by `lit` or transformation of `lit` column). You can look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69318014/why-schema-of-json-fails/69327950#69327950) to [Why schema_of_json fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69318014/6807769) question for more details. And also [What is a foldable column ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69328739/what-is-a-foldable-column) question